# Ruby Postgresl group statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I have the following postgresql statement which works ok in navicat for Postgresql,

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', updated_at), count(*) as total_count 
FROM "persons"
WHERE ("persons"."updated_at" BETWEEN '2012-10-17 00:00:00.000000' AND '2012-11-07   12:25:04.082224') 
GROUP BY date_trunc('day',updated_at)
ORDER BY count(updated_at) DESC
```

I get expected results like

```
2012-10-31 00:00:00,5
2012-11-06 00:00:00,2
2012-11-05 00:00:00,1
```

I need to convert this to ruby for a RoR project

I've written this statement as follows

```
persons = where(updated_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
persons = persons.group("date(updated_at)")
persons = persons.select("updated_at, count(*) as total_count")
persons = persons.order("count(updated_at)")
```

however i get the following error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "persons.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT updated_at, count(*) as total_count FROM "persons"  WH...
           ^
: SELECT updated_at, count(*) as total_count FROM "persons"  WHERE ("persons"."updated_at"     BETWEEN '2012-10-17 00:00:00.000000' AND '2012-11-07 14:38:54.674684') GROUP BY     date(persons.updated_at) ORDER BY count(updated_at)
```

any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try

```
persons = where(updated_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
persons = persons.group("date(updated_at), updated_at")
persons = persons.select("updated_at, count(*) as total_count")
persons = persons.order("count(updated_at)")
```

or

```
persons = where(updated_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
persons = persons.group("date(updated_at)")
persons = persons.select("date(updated_at), count(*) as total_count")
persons = persons.order("count(updated_at)")
```

or

```
persons = persons.find(:all, 
                       :select => "updated_at, count(*) as total_count",
                       :group => "updated_at",
                       :order => "count(updated_at)")
```

Comment: I've used the middle option you specified with some success but now I'm getting another error.  ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: status.   status is an attribute on my Person class.

Comment: I've also tried to refine the query to, passes = where(updated_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
        passes = passes.group("date(updated_at)")
        passes = passes.select("date(updated_at), count(*) as total_count").   but now i get (Object doesn't support #inspect)

Comment: sorry that should be persons not passes

Comment: hmm perhaps you could post the code for the person model. As I would think this would have something to do with the model code

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting `updated_at`, but you are grouping on `date(updated_at)`.  You either need to group on `updated_at` (which probably doesn't make any sense) or change your select so that you are selecting `date(updated_at)`.

In other words, take Jon Day's second example.